# Change Value of Object Once Added To Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My state looks like so:

```
items: [
  { id: 1, name: 'banana', price: 100, quantity: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'apple', price: 200, quantity: 1 },
  { id: 3, name: 'blueberry', price: 300, quantity: 1 }
]

cart: []
```

I have a function where I push the item to the cart:

```
addItem = item => {
  const { cart, total, itemQuantity } = this.state
  const { price, id } = item
  const i = cart.indexOf(item)

  if (!cart.some(x => x.id === id)) {
    this.setState({
      cart: [...cart, { ...item, quantity: itemQuantity }],
      total: total + (price * itemQuantity)
    })
  }
}
```

I'm checking to see if the item exists before adding it to avoid duplicates. What I want to happen is if the item is already added to the `cart`, I want to find that object and change its quantity value.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
addItem = item => {
  const { cart, total, itemQuantity } = this.state
  const { price, id } = item
  const index = cart.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
  let quantity = itemQuantity;

  const newCart = index === -1 
     ? [...cart, {...item, quantity }] 
     : cart.map((it, i) => {
           if (i === index) {
             quantity = it.quantity + quantity;
             return { ...it, quantity }
           } else return it
       });

  this.setState({
    cart: newCart,
    total: total + (price * quantity)
  });

}
```

Comment: This will always push a new object.

Comment: It pushes the object regardless if it's there

Comment: @RogerFedFan Yeah sorry, that was caused by the naming collision of having the map also use the item variable, updated it.

Comment: Your solution works, I just had to change the index constant to be `cart.findIndex(x => x.id === id)` and everything worked as planned.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution below would work for you without having to update your design much. You really just have to call `Array.prototype` method `reduce` on an array of items you wish to add to the cart. Make sure to pass your `cart`'s current state as the initial value to `reduce` (pass it as the second argument). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

With some simple logic, you could just check to see if the item id already exists in the cart (which is just an object literal keyed by item id). If it doesn't, add the object and set the quantity property to 1 - if it does, just increment the quantity property by 1.

Hopefully the example below is clear and can help you out:

```js
//an array of items we want to add to the cart
var items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'banana',
    price: 100,
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'apple',
    price: 200,
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'blueberry',
    price: 300,
    quantity: 1
  }
];

//function utilizing reduce to update our cart object
function updateCart(cartToUpdate, itemsToAdd) {
  itemsToAdd.reduce(function(cart, cartItem) {
    if (!cart[cartItem.id]) {
      cart[cartItem.id] = {
        name: cartItem.name,
        price: cartItem.price,
        quantity: 1
      }
    } else {
      cart[cartItem.id].quantity++;
    }

    return cart;
  }, cart);
}

//implement cart as an object keyed on item id
var cart = {
  1: {
    name: 'banana',
    price: 100,
    quantity: 1
  }
};
//i manually added a single banana to the cart so we can show that our update function works properly

console.log('Cart before update:');
console.log(cart);

updateCart(cart, items);

console.log('Cart after update:');
console.log(cart);

//from here it's really easy to see how many of each item we have in the cart:
Object.keys(cart).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(`The customer has ${cart[key].quantity} ${cart[key].name}(s) in their cart`)
});
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just leverage the `i` const that you've already defined!

```
addItem = item => {
  const { cart, total, itemQuantity } = this.state
  const { price, id } = item
  const i = cart.indexOf(item)
  const newCart = [...cart]
  const newTotal = total + (price * itemQuantity)

  if (i !== -1) {
    const newItem =  { ...item, quantity: itemQuantity + 1 }

    newCart[i] = newItem

    this.setState({
      cart: newCart,
      total: newTotal,
    })

    return
  }

  newCart.push({ ...item, quantity: itemQuantity })

  this.setState({
    cart: newCart,
    total: newTotal,
  })
}
```

Note, it was unclear how you wanted the `total` functionality to work, so I've left that as it is. This, however will update the item you're looking for.

Comment: `i` will not equal `undefined` it returns the index or -1

Comment: Edit updated: (i !== -1). If the `indexOf` of an item in an array is `-1` - it means it's not in the array.

Comment: Testing your solution, it still adds the item regardless

Answer (score 0):

I had to check to see whether the item was added to the cart before pushing a new object with that item.

I then had to find the index of that item in the cart and update its quantity.

```
addItem = item => {
  const { cart, total, itemQuantity } = this.state
  const { price, id } = item
  const i = cart.findIndex(x => x.id === id)

  if (!cart.some(x => x.id === id)) {
    this.setState({
      cart: [
        ...cart,
        { ...item, quantity: itemQuantity }
      ]
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      cart: [
        ...cart.slice(0, i),
        { ...cart[i], quantity: cart[i].quantity + itemQuantity },
        ...cart.slice(i + 1)
      ]
    })
  }

  this.setState({
    total: total + (price * itemQuantity)
  })
}
```

Comment: You really should try and not do successive `setState()` calls like this, you are causing two re-renders where only one is needed

Comment: @deowk thanks for the suggestion! I'll see if I can refactor it for better practice

Comment: Give my answer another try it should work for you now that it has been updated, happy travels...;)